# How to add CSS if element has more than one child?

Tags: html, css

I have `td` tags and a several `div` inside `td`:

```
<td>
   <div class='test'></div>
   <div class='test'></div>
</td>

<td>
   <div class='test'></div>  
</td>
```

I want to add `margin-bottom` to `div` if there are more than one in the `td`. How can I do this with the css?

Comment: Show us what did you try. Plus I don't think you can control every `div` on a `td` only if there are several elements with CSS.

Comment: I can do this only with js. But, I don't have idea how can I do this by css

Comment: You want to add `margin-bottom` to *each* `div` if there are more than one? Or to all `div` but the first? or..?

Comment: @gvee: only if there are more than one

Comment: So to **all** `div` in each `td` if there is more than one `div`?

Comment: @gvee: yes, to all divs

Comment: @user348173 - you CAN do this wih css - using the nth-last-child selector. no js is required. (see my answer)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can't directly 'count' total numbers of elements in CSS, so there's no way to only apply the class if there's 2 or more divs (you'd need JavaScript for that).

But a possible workaround is to apply the class to all divs in the td...

```
td > div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

... and then override/disable it with a different style when there's only one element. That indirectly lets you add the style when there's 2+ more child elements.

```
td > div:only-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Alternatively you can apply to every div after the first one, if that happens to work for your situation.

```
td > div:not(:first-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Edit: Or as Itay says in the comment, use a sibling selector

```
td > div + div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use siblings selectors.

Comment: You can *kind of* count in CSS: see `:nth-of-type`

Comment: Won't the `~` be more suitable than `+`?

Comment: @Mikel - you can actually do this with css - see my answer

Answer (score 17):

```
td > div:not(:only-child) { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Comment: Works for two child elements but not 3+ (at least for me)

Comment: @paul it worked for me, could it be because it should be written instead `td div:not(:only-child) { margin-bottom: 10px; }`

Answer (score 12):

Well actually you can do this with css using the `nth-last-child` selector

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/b88TX/3/)**

So if your markup was like this:

```
<table>
<td>
   <div class='test'>test</div>
   <div class='test'>test</div>
</td>
</table>

<hr />

<table>
<td>
   <div class='test'>test</div>  
</td>

</table>
```

### CSS

```
div:nth-last-child(n+2) ~ div:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

... the above css will style the last div element only if there exists a container that has at least 2 child divs

Just to see how this works better - here's another **[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/b88TX/4/)**

Comment: DanieldD, I was completely unaware you can have (introductory) if statements in CSS using "~".  Do you know where I can read up some more on this?  I learned something today! Woohoo!

Comment: @Joey read up on adjacent selectors ... essentially `+` for direct adjacent e.g. `div + div` will target a div following another; `~` is for general adjacency where `div ~ div` means any div that follows after another div, even if there are other elements in-between.

Comment: @Danield your solution only applies the margin to the *last* element when there is more than one child ... I believe that the requirement was for all divs to have a bottom margin.

Answer (score 7):

did a nice little combo with the accepted answer

only applies style to the first child when its NOT the only child.. so when there is more than 1

```
td > div:not(:only-child):first-child { }
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS-Has has [limited browser](https://caniuse.com/css-has) support:

but here you go:

```
td:not(:has(div:first-child:last-child))
```

bonus:

```
td:not(:has(div:only-child))
```

Comment: oh and you can count elements using "counter-increment:"

Comment: This will be amazing when it's supported by a browser! https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

Comment: Attention, `:has` isn't supported and I do think that it wont never be https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 2):

i think there is no way to add the 10px margin to each div inside a td without the use of css3.

so a solution would be to use javascript and check if there are more than 1 div's inside the td and then if yes add  a special class.

css

```
.myMarginClass div{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

js

```
var td=document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
l=td.length;
while(l--){
 if(td[l].getElementsByTagName('div').length>1){
  td[l].className='myMarginClass';
 }
}
```

else for modern browsers the proper solution is the `:only-child`
proposed by @mikel

Answer (score 0):

If there are other kinds of elements inside the `td`, you can still select the only `div` with this `:only-of-type`

```
<td>
   <div class='test'></div>
   <div class='test'></div>
</td>

<td>
   <div class='test'></div>
   <p class='test'></p>  
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
td > div:only-of-type{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```