# Display only if there is more than 2 children

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the css to show a box only if there are more than 2 children?

Example:

```
// Don't show
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>

// Show
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do it with CSS only. Is it possible?

Comment: Nop it isn't possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add CSS if element has more than one child?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738052/how-to-add-css-if-element-has-more-than-one-child)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, read the question before assignin a flag to it!

Comment: If later you are interested on a Jquery solution https://jsfiddle.net/oe9amvzb/1/

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `:only-child` selector and hide the li if it's the only one.

```
ul li:only-child{
  display: none;
}
```

```css
ul li:only-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Don't Display</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Display</li>
  <li>Display</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90kx009u/

---

Here's the JS if you wanted to accomplish exactly what you're asking:

```
let thelist = document.querySelector('.thelist')

if(thelist.childElementCount <= 1){
    thelist.remove()
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90kx009u/2/

Comment: But this will still display the container, which is the element he's trying to control.

Comment: @Utkanos correct but is the best OP can get with just CSS +1 ... As noted will fail to hide the entire element so if you have for example a pseudo it will show https://jsfiddle.net/90kx009u/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly 'count' total numbers of elements in CSS, so there's no way to only apply the class if there's 2 or more divs (you'd need JavaScript for that)
See more here: [How to add CSS if element has more than one child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738052/how-to-add-css-if-element-has-more-than-one-child)