# Is correct using empty div with fixed height for spaces in a website?

Tags: html, css

To build a website I usually insert some empty divs with fixed height for having a vertical spaces I need. I'm wondering if that is correct or is there other better way to handle vertical spaces with HTML / CSS.
E.g.:

```
<head>
<style>
.space-20{height: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<div class="site">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<p>
  <div class="space-20"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<p>
  <div class="space-20"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<p>
</div>
```

Comment: No. It's incorrect. Use margings and paddings of an actual element.

Comment: ok, thanks. Obiously I use margins or padding for some elementes. But I still see my way is clean for vertical spaces. But did you ever use (eg) .div{height: 10px} for vertical spaces?

Comment: Why do you consider this "cleaner" than using the margin and padding attributes? Just because it looks the way you want doesn't mean it's the correct way to do it. There are many problems with your approach that can be mitigated with using CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `margin-top`, and `margin-bottom` as needed. **Using `<div>` elements for spacing is bad practice.** Here's an example using these CSS attributes to give vertical space both above and below some elements:

HTML

```
<div>Top text</div>
<div class="spaceAbove">Hello</div>
<div>Middle text</div>
<div class="spaceBelow">World</div>
<div>Bottom text</div>
```

CSS

```
.spaceAbove {
    padding-top: 20px;
    //margin-top: 20px;
}

.spaceBelow {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    //margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

See the MDN page on the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) for more information on when and how to use these.

But for your code, I would take a slightly different approach. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738052/how-to-add-css-if-element-has-more-than-one-child) for some interesting and possibly cleaner alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, Bucket. I used css a lot and my point of view is: better using empty divs with height rather then add lot of css code to other elements. I don't see anything wrong so far. Maybe my example is not perfectly clear.. sorry for that.
Did you ever use (eg) .div{height: 10px} for vertical spaces?

Comment: @DavidS - Your example made sense, and your question is clear. No, I do not use blank divs for vertical height. My answer is that **this is bad practice.** It is better to add CSS to elements to give them space, as this is exactly what CSS is intended for; divs are meant to encapsulate content, not to act as a buffer between elements. If you think using CSS clutters your code, consider moving it to its own .css file instead of writing it in your <head>. HTML should only describe what the page looks like, and CSS is your tool for making it look the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, I got it. :)

Comment: Of course. Please mark this question solved if we have sufficiently answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use margin-bottom that's what i usually do.

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

*you can see it here* [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j0tf7h42/)